# MySQL Replace Null with an Empty String

Tags: python, mysql

I have this table

| user_id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABCD |
| 1 | *null* |
| 2 | EFGH |

I'am trying to get all the titles of every user id and convert null to an empty string.

I tried using this

`SELECT IFNULL(title, '') FROM table WHERE user_id = 1`

But it says that multiple rows returned, when I try 2 it returns a result.

Is there a way to convert all null relut to empty string if ther more than 1 result? Thanks.

Comment: If its just the conversion you want, `UPDATE table SET title='' WHERE title IS NULL`

Comment: What result would you expect for user_id 1 if there would be no null value in your input table? Just one of the input rows? A concatenation of all titles? Is it not possible in your domain to have more than one non-null title per user?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySql Query Replace NULL with Empty String in Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560723/mysql-query-replace-null-with-empty-string-in-select)

Answer (score 1):

You can use COALESCE() to replace NULL with an empty string.

Comment: you should show a little more in an answer, like how it matches to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a detailed answer on the following [link](https://digitalrivertutorials.blogspot.com/2022/02/how-to-substitute-null-values-in-mysql.html).

Hope it resolves your issue.

Thanks

Comment: Try to provide at least a summary of the solution so this is not a `link-only-answer`. You can read more about it here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info#:~:text=Link%2Donly%20answers%20are%20answers,information%20available%20on%20another%20page.