# Replace null values where the datatype is numeric with just a blank

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE kpi.data
SET MetricValue = ''
WHERE (MetricValue IS NULL ) 
  and PeriodDate  =  '2020-01-02'
     and ReportID = 4
```

I  got this error

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 4 Error converting data type varchar
> to numeric.

Comment: SQL Server (MS SQL) <> MySQL

Comment: *I tried to set null to blank but got this error because the data is of the numeric datatype.* Your output column must be of char type, not numeric one.

Comment: The sql way of indicating there is no value is NULL , can you explain why you want to do this given there are ways of dealing with null eg coalesce in selects etc..

Comment: Noway to store string value in numeric column.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do does not make any sense, so it cannot work, and it will not work.

- If the data type of a column is numeric then the column can only contain numbers.
- If the data type of a column is numeric and nullable the column can contain either a number or null.

There is no other value that a numeric field can receive, either in MySQL or in any other relational database that I have ever heard of.

Perhaps what you want to do is to convert null to blank when selecting, (not when inserting/updating,) in which case you should look at some other Q&A like this one: [MySql Query Replace NULL with Empty String in Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560723/mysql-query-replace-null-with-empty-string-in-select)

Comment: I want to update where it to blank where the value is null

Comment: And I want steak-flavored earplugs. But I cannot have any.